# Future of the "fun" tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I suggest we get rid of the [fun](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/fun) tag. The questions are mostly wikis, closed or both and I think it matches all criterion for a meta tag.

Comment: Why on earth did @TomWij even start adding these to questions in the first place?

Comment: Super User is not meant to be a "fun" place ;)

Comment: Well I've started deleting some of the more obvious wtf questions

Comment: @IvoFlipse: Well, to group the questions together so you can more easily get rid of them. Furthermore, there was also a humor tag in the past so I merged those small amount of questions to the fun tag...

Comment: Just flag them, so we could have gotten rid of them

Comment: @IvoFlispe: True, I'm not flagging enough. I was unsure though... :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Tag burninated!

Beware of new questions with [untagged](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/untagged)